# Debugging 502 Bad Gateway error - Ubuntu, Nginx, Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, server, unicorn

I have an EC2 instance, trying to run a Rails app with Nginx and Unicorn.

I keep getting a 502 Bad Gateway error after about 60 seconds:

Here's what I get in the nginx error log:

> 2017/02/10 18:03:38 [error] 13208#13208: *1 upstream prematurely
>   closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   174.25.146.24, server: _, request: "GET /welcome HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/rails/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock:/welcome",
>   host: "mydomain.com"

unicorn.stderr.log

> E, [2017-02-13T00:58:12.456504 #13149] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:16535
>   timeout (31s > 30s), killing E, [2017-02-13T00:58:12.459388 #13149]
>   ERROR -- : reaped #
>   worker=0 I, [2017-02-13T00:58:12.459499 #13149]  INFO -- : worker=0
>   spawning... I, [2017-02-13T00:58:12.461390 #16810]  INFO -- : worker=0
>   spawned pid=16810 I, [2017-02-13T00:58:12.461829 #16810]  INFO -- :
>   worker=0 ready

nginx.conf

```
user rails;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        #  upstream unicorn {
        #    server unix:/home/rails/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
        #  }
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

unicorn.rb

```
# set path to application
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}"
working_directory app_dir

print shared_dir

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 2
preload_app true
timeout 30
print '1'

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64
print '2'

# Logging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

print '3'
# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
print '4'
```

sites-available/default

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/rails/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /home/rails/myapp/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Permissions on the socket:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 rails rails 0 Feb 10 18:00 unicorn.sock
```

Any ideas on how I can track this down?

Comment: Is there anything in the unicorn log?

Comment: I just added that towards the top of the post

Comment: Would you be able to provide log of 'unicorn.stdout.log' ?

Answer (score 5):

Your Rails application is failing to return a response to the Unicorn HTTP server within the amount of time configured by your timeout settings (currently 30 seconds, as configured by the `timeout 30` line in your `unicorn.rb`).

Either increase the [`timeout`](https://bogomips.org/unicorn/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-timeout) setting in your `unicorn.rb`, or (preferably) debug why your Rails application is taking > 30 seconds to respond to a request.

Comment: hi @wjordan, i am facing a similar issue, how do i identify which request is taking more than 30 seconds. I see mixture of action cable and other actions

Comment: @opensource-developer the [correct way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/2518355) to ask a follow-up question is to ask a new question, linking back to the original for context.